# Impala SQL return top 3 grouped records

Tags: sql, subquery, greatest-n-per-group, impala

I have this table example on impala.I want to get max top *number_of_call* for each caller

*caller and group_id are unique grouped together*

```
caller | group_id |number_of_call
  23   | 4433     | 12
  45   |  342     | 5
  23   |  475     | 33
  45   |  732     | 9
  46   |  4433    | 2
  23   |  522     | 5
  45   |  475     | 54
  23   |  342     | 32
  45   |  342     | 43
```

**Expected output**

```
  caller   | group_id | number_of_call
     23    |   475    | 33
     23    |   342    | 32
     23    |   4433   | 12
     46    |   4433   | 2
     45    |   475    | 54
     45    |   342    | 43
     45    |   732    | 9
```

Comment: . . You have enough reputation that you should know how to tag questions with correct database tags.

Comment: i tagged other database because SQL is a global languages not specific for a database.you should know this you have enough reputation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use window functions to adress this greatest-n-per-group problem:

```
select *
from 
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by caller order by number_of_calls desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn <= 3
order by caller, rn
```

In the subquery, `row_number()` ranks records having the same `caller` by descending `number_of_calls`. Then, the outer query filters on the top 3 records per `caller`.